# How to save data from WPF application to file?

Tags: c#

I'm building a WPF application with Visual Studio in which I need to save data from the application to file when closing it and when I open the application, it load the data from the file to continue working. What type of file do I need to use and how to read/write the file?

In school, I know that in C++ you can read from .INP file and write on .OUT file but I guess that's not the case here. I think I could save data as text to a .txt file and convert the data to its original type but this way seems to be inefficient.

It would be better if I can read and write to the same file.

Comment: You read and write data in a WPF program the same way you'd do it in _any_ .NET program. Using one of the many different file I/O related API methods available to do that. There's nothing unique about WPF when it comes to dealing with data persistence, and your question is way too broad. The documentation is full of useful examples and references to help you understand how file I/O in .NET works.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little sample code. You can use any file extension you want

```
//Allows you to perform file IO:
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace TryStuff2019 {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnSaveToFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var saveThisToFile = "This is some sample text to save";
            var fileName = "MyOutput.txt";

            //This will save some text to a file in the same folder as your project exe file
            using(StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(fileName)) {
                sw.Write(saveThisToFile);
            }
        }

        private void BtnReadFromFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var inputFileName = "MyOutput.txt";
            string fileContents;
            using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(inputFileName)) {
                fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            txtData.Text = fileContents;
        }
    }
}
```